# How to recode and count efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large csv with three strings per row in this form:

```
a,c,d
c,a,e
f,g,f
a,c,b
c,a,d
b,f,s
c,a,c
```

I read in the first two columns recode the strings  to integers and then remove duplicates counting how many copies of each row there were as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", usecols=[0,1], prefix="ID_", header=None)
letters = set(df.values.flat)
df.replace(to_replace=letters, value=range(len(letters)), inplace=True)
df1 = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).size().rename('count').reset_index()
print df1
```

This gives:

```
   ID_0  ID_1  count
0     0     1      2
1     1     0      3
2     2     4      1
3     4     3      1
```

which is exactly what I need.

However as my data is large I would like to make two improvements.

- How can I do the groupby and then recode instead of the other way round? The problem is that I can't do `df1[['ID_0','ID_0']].replace(to_replace=letters, value=range(len(letters)), inplace = True)`. This gives the error

  > "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame"
- How can I avoid creating df1? That is do the whole thing inplace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use [`sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to do the letter to digit conversion:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Perform the groupby (before converting letters to digits).
df = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).size().rename('count').reset_index()

# Initialize the LabelEncoder.
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].values.flat)

# Convert to digits.
df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']] = df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].apply(le.transform)
```

The resulting output:

```
   ID_0  ID_1  count
0     0     2      2
1     1     3      1
2     2     0      3
3     3     4      1
```

If you want to convert back to letters at a later point in time, you can use `le.inverse_transform`:

```
df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']] = df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].apply(le.inverse_transform)
```

Which maps back as expected:

```
  ID_0 ID_1  count
0    a    c      2
1    b    f      1
2    c    a      3
3    f    g      1
```

If you just want to know which digit corresponds to which letter, you can look at the `le.classes_` attribute.  This will give you an array of letters, which is indexed by the digit it encodes to:

```
le.classes_ 

['a' 'b' 'c' 'f' 'g']
```

For a more visual representation, you can cast as a Series:

```
pd.Series(le.classes_)

0    a
1    b
2    c
3    f
4    g
```

**Timings**

Using a larger version of the sample data and the following setup:

```
df2 = pd.concat([df]*10**5, ignore_index=True)

def root(df):
    df = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).size().rename('count').reset_index()
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].values.flat)
    df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']] = df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].apply(le.transform)
    return df

def pir2(df):
    unq = np.unique(df)
    mapping = pd.Series(np.arange(unq.size), unq)
    return df.stack().map(mapping).unstack() \
      .groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit root(df2)
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop

%timeit pir2(df2)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.69 s per loop
```

Comment: That's very nice! I think I will copy your idea.

Answer (score 2):

***New Answer***

```
unq = np.unique(df)
mapping = pd.Series(np.arange(unq.size), unq)

df.stack().map(mapping).unstack() \
  .groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

[image]

***Old Answer***

```
df.stack().rank(method='dense').astype(int).unstack() \
  .groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

[image]

Comment: I need to store the mapping from the original strings to integers. This is given explicitly in the method in my question. Can you get it from yours as well?

Comment: Small thing: I need  the ids to start at 0, not 1.