# Can dask be used to groupby and recode out of core?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have 8GB csv files and 8GB of RAM. Each file has two strings per row in this form:

```
a,c
c,a
f,g
a,c
c,a
b,f
c,a
```

For smaller files I remove duplicates counting how many copies of each row there were in the first two columns and then recode the strings  to integers [as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39419342/2179021):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
df = pd.read_csv("file.txt", header=None, prefix="ID_")

# Perform the groupby (before converting letters to digits).
df = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).size().rename('count').reset_index()

# Initialize the LabelEncoder.
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].values.flat)

# Convert to digits.
df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']] = df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].apply(le.transform)
```

This gives:

```
   ID_0  ID_1  count
0     0     1      2
1     1     0      3
2     2     4      1
3     4     3      1
```

which is exactly what I need for this toy example.

For the larger file I can't take these steps because of lack of RAM.

I can imagine  it is possible to combine unix sort and a bespoke python solution doing multiple passes over the data to process my data set. But someone suggested dask might be suitable.  Having read the docs I am still not clear.

> Can dask be used to do this sort of out of core processing or is there some other out of core pandas solution?

Comment: dask is a wise way to go: see the answer below and don't give up if you encounter issues.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the grouped dataframe fits your memory, the change you would have to make to your code should be pretty minor. Here's my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
from dask import dataframe as dd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# import the data as dask dataframe, 100mb per partition
# note, that at this point no data is read yet, dask will read the files
# once compute or get is called.
df = dd.read_csv("file.txt", header=None, prefix="ID_", blocksize=100000000)

# Perform the groupby (before converting letters to digits).
# For better understanding, let's split this into two parts:
#     (i) define the groupby operation on the dask dataframe and call compute()
#     (ii) compute returns a pandas dataframe, which we can then use for further analysis
pandas_df = df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).apply(lambda x: len(x), columns=0).compute()
pandas_df = pandas_df.rename('count').reset_index()

# Initialize the LabelEncoder.
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(pandas_df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].values.flat)

# Convert to digits.
pandas_df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']] = pandas_df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].apply(le.transform)
```

One possible solution in pandas would be to read the files in chunks (passing the chunksize argument to read_csv), running the groupby on individual chunks and combining the results.

---

Here's how you can solve the problem in pure python:

```
counts = {}
with open('data') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        id1, id2 = line.rstrip().split(',')
        counts[(id1, id2)] = 1 + counts.get((id1, id2), 0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[(k[0], k[1], v) for k, v in counts.items()],
                  columns=['ID_0', 'ID_1', 'count'])
# apply label encoding etc.
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].values.flat)

# Convert to digits.
df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']] = df[['ID_0', 'ID_1']].apply(le.transform)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your pandas  suggestion seems difficult as I am not sure how you would combine the results.  Would you be able to add some code for that please?

Comment: The pandas solution would involve combining individual groupby results (by adding the counts of (ID_0, ID_1)-tuples for each chunk). The easiest way to solve your specific problem would be to simply read the file, counting as you go. I have added code for that - or were you rather after a general recipe for performing large groupbys?

Comment: Thank you for the edit. One problem with using a dict is that it's very memory inefficient in Python.

Comment: LabelEncoder turns out to be very slow on large datasets. This a known flaw but in the meantime a dict is much faster.